# Bootstrap table how hidden, when toggled visible using javascript it does not show correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table. I am using css to hide one of the table rows initially. I have a checkbox that I want to show the hidden table row if it is selected, otherwise it should not show the row. I have it working, but when the checkbox is selected, the format (width) of the now visible row is out of whack (not aligned). I tried playing with the css for this hidden row (width, display inline-table...) but I cannot get it to work.

CSS:

```
 #hiddenRow {
       display: none;
    }
    .orderTotal {
       padding: 10px;
       background-color: #fdfbe4;
       width: 95%;
       margin: 0 auto;  
    }
    .orderTotal h4 {
       font-weight: bold;   
    }
    .totalOrder {
       color: #ee7a23;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 18px; 
    }
    .totalAmount {
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 18px; 
    }
```

Table html:

```
<div class="orderTotal">
   <h4>Order Total:</h4

   <table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Item1</td>
         <td class="price-1">50</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="hiddenRow">
         <td>Item2</td>
         <td class="price-2">13</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Item3</td>
        <td class="price-3">30</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="summary">
        <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
        <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
       </tr>

     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

JS to show hidden table row:

```
// hide table row from order total if not checked
$("input[name='product_CD']").on("click", function() {
    $("#hiddenRow").toggleClass('show');
});
```

Here is a screenshot of how the row displays when the checkbox is selected.

Notice how the width of the row and the price column is not aligned. It previews fine if the row is not initially hidden and it also toggles visible/hidden fine in a browser when inspecting the element and manually toggling the `#hiddenRow` `display:none` css on and off.

[image]

Comment: How is defined the `show` class ? Have you tried `display: table-row;` ?

Comment: I noticed that the `h4` closing tag on line 2 is not closed, but that did not solve the problem for me. As Louys Patrice Bessette said, changing the `show` class to `display: table-row !important;` instead of the bootstrap default of `display: block !important` fixes the issue for me. [This codepen](http://codepen.io/vladdobra/pen/NRBYaO) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ov7d9rLa/

I think the problem might have been due to fighting between using bootstrap and CSS for hiding/showing. I simplified this by using the bootstrap class "hidden", and toggling that class with the click event.

```
<div class="orderTotal">
   <h4>Order Total:</h4>

   <table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Item1</td>
         <td class="price-1">50</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id='hiddenRow' class="hidden">
         <td>Item2</td>
         <td class="price-2">13</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Item3</td>
        <td class="price-3">30</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="summary">
        <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
        <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
       </tr>

     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>

 <button id='toggle' class='btn btn-primary'>
Toggle
</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#toggle").on("click", function() {
    $("#hiddenRow").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use all of that css. jQuery makes it 100x's cleaner in my opinion. Here's what I would do:

I'd take advantage of jQuery's `hide()` and `toggle()`. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Hide the row when the page loads
  $("#hiddenRow").hide();

  // when the user clicks the checkbox, toggle the row
  $("#toggleCheck").click(function() {

    $("#hiddenRow").toggle();

  })

});
```

Here's a full JSBin: **http://jsbin.com/nokusunamo/edit?html,js,console,output**

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/200/)**.

Just use `display: table-row` as suggested **@Louys** in **[above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048022/bootstrap-table-how-hidden-when-toggled-visible-using-javascript-it-does-not-sh/40048269#comments-40048022)** :

```
#hiddenRow.show{
     display: table-row;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("input[name='product_CD']").on("click", function() {
  $("#hiddenRow").toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
#hiddenRow {
  display: none;
}
.orderTotal {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fdfbe4;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;  
}
.orderTotal h4 {
  font-weight: bold;   
}
.totalOrder {
  color: #ee7a23;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px; 
}
.totalAmount {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px; 
}

#hiddenRow.show{
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name='product_CD' type="checkbox" />
<div class="orderTotal">
  <h4>Order Total:</h4>

  <table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item1</td>
        <td class="price-1">50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="hiddenRow">
        <td>Item2</td>
        <td class="price-2">13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item3</td>
        <td class="price-3">30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="summary">
        <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
        <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rex is that not what you looking for?

Comment: The bootstrap keyword was important here... I got it when I read @vladdobra's comment below mine. [See here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide) for this particular bootstrap default. +1 anyway ;)