# How would I toggle this table so that only the rows are hidden when it is clicked with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to figure out how I could hide the rows in these tables when the table head is clicked? I'm using bootstrap 5 so JQuery isn't available

```
<table class="table table-info table-bordered">
                <thead id="tablea">  <!-- Table head -->
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Column 2</th>
                    <th scope="col">Column 3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table tables" id="body-a" data-action="hide">
                  {% for row in a %}
                  <tr> <!--Table rows -->
                    <td>{{row.column2}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.column3}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
</table>

 <table class="table table-info table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Column 2</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table tables" id="body-b" data-action="hide">
                  {% for row in b %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{row.column2}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can do that completely on bootstrap but you can use custom css file using toggleclass in javaScript, check this answer if it helps [Bootstrap table how hidden, when toggled visible using javascript it does not show correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048022/bootstrap-table-how-hidden-when-toggled-visible-using-javascript-it-does-not-sh/40048269#comments-40048022)

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap 5, you can hide an element by adding the d-none class to it.

```
<div class="d-none">div hidden</div>
```

To hide or show the body table in your first table (tablea), you could write the javascript code below :

```
document.getElementById('tablea').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById('body-a').classList.toggle('d-none');
});
```

[here is a demo](https://codepen.io/lebr1/pen/oNMoPyQ)